# $add,$subtract aggregation-framework in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hi i am mentioning the sample data
///collection - test////

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2020-02-11T17:00:00Z"),
                "userId" : ObjectId("5e43e5cdc11f750864f46820"),
                "adminId" : ObjectId("5e43de778b57693cd46859eb")
        },
        "outstanding" : 212.39999999999998,
        "totalBill" : 342.4,
        "totalPayment" : 130
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2020-02-11T17:00:00Z"),
                "userId" : ObjectId("5e43e73169fe1e3fc07eb7c5"),
                "adminId" : ObjectId("5e43de778b57693cd46859eb")
        },
        "outstanding" : 797.8399999999999,
        "totalBill" : 797.8399999999999,
        "totalPayment" : 0
}
```

I need to structure a query which does following things-

1. I need to calculate the actualOutstanding:`[(totalBill+outstanding)-totalPayment]`,
2. I need to save this actualOutstanding in the same collection & in the same document according to  `{"_id" : {"date","userId", "adminId" }}`

   **NOTE**: `userId` is different in both the documents.

Comment: What did you try so far? SO is not a homeworking-service.

Comment: Any specific reason that you need to save `AcutalOutstanding` to the docs? It seems to me that that would be redundant, since you already have the data to easily calculate it. You might want to look into [virtual properties](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html)

Comment: Why do you store redundant data? `outstanding` and `totalPayment` are redundant, you should store only one of them.

Comment: @ – Wernfried Domscheit db.payment1.aggregate([{
 
    
        '$match': {
            '_id.adminId': ObjectId('5e43de778b57693cd46859eb'),
            '_id.userId': ObjectId('5e43e5cdc11f750864f46820'),
            '_id.date': ISODate("2020-02-1117:00:00Z"),
        },
       
} ,{
$project: {
    totalBill: 1, 
    outstanding1: 
    {
        $add: ['$totalBill','$outstanding'],
    }, }}
]) this is what i have tried along with other queries newOutstanding is resulting null always and $merge is ctreating a new document everytime which i dont want that too with a null value

Comment: @- – Wernfried Domscheit  i need actualOutstanding because from the next day if i calculate to actualOutstanding then i need not hit the payment collection to calculate totalpayment every time, if i can achieve this in this way then i just need to calculate outstanding form this collection only. if u can help me

Comment: @ – Enslev  yes to certain extent your are right but the way architecture had been designed i want to avoid hitting the payment collection everytime even, at-least if u can help me achieve actualOutstanding:[(totalBill+outstanding)-totalPayment]

Comment: what mongo version are you on?

Comment: -– tom slabbaert its 4.2 please check my answer too i already have tried $merge and $out i know we can save a new filed in the same collection using merge & out , any other way ??

Answer (score 2):

Introduced in Mongo version 4.2+ [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2/#availability), meaning we can now use aggregate expressions to update documents.

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {
       "adminId" : ObjectId("5e43de778b57693cd46859eb")
       '_id."userId" : ObjectId("5e43e73169fe1e3fc07eb7c5"),
       '_id.date': ISODate("2020-02-11T18:30:00Z"),
    },
    [
        { '$set': { 
              actualOutstanding: {
                  $subtract:[ {$add: ['$totalBill','$outstanding']},'$totalPayment']
             }
        } }
    ]);
```

For any other Mongo version you have to split it into 2 actions, first query and calculate then update the document with the calculation.